# setContentView behave in strange way

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

I am trying to swap between Fragments, and one of the answers was: you cannot remove a fragment which built statically in XML file, the I create a container XML file and use setContentView() to set the container as firs UI,
 here is my container file (called conrainer_new.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

  <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/second_screen"
        android:name="com.eiq.randomsendriod.Secund_screen"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/conver_list_frag"
        android:name="com.eiq.randomsendriod.ConverList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainpage"
        android:name="com.eiq.randomsendriod.mainpage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
     <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/massenger"
        android:name="com.eiq.randomsendriod.Massenger_frag.java"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and in the onCreate method I do:

```
    @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.container_new);
}
```

**the result:**
the application crashes and in the LogCat screen I get:

```
11-22 16:10:11.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1184): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.eiq.randomsendriod/com.eiq.randomsendriod.SendRandom}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-22 16:10:11.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1184):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
11-22 16:10:11.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1184):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
11-22 16:10:11.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1184):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-22 16:10:11.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1184):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
11-22 16:10:11.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1184):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-22 16:10:11.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1184):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-22 16:10:11.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1184):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
11-22 16:10:11.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1184):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-22 16:10:11.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1184):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-22 16:10:11.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1184):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
11-22 16:10:11.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1184):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
11-22 16:10:11.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1184):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-22 16:10:11.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1184): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-22 16:10:11.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1184):  at com.eiq.randomsendriod.SendRandom.onCreate(SendRandom.java:82)
11-22 16:10:11.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1184):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
11-22 16:10:11.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1184):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-22 16:10:11.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1184):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
11-22 16:10:11.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1184):  ... 11 more
```

### **if I set another fragment other than the container  the application works fine, but cannot change the UI with another fragment!**

Solved by changing the above XML file to :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
```

and delete all the other code!

Comment: Have you tried removing "android:name=" from each of the FrameLayouts ?

Comment: I solve the problem by removing all the framelayouts, and convert the LinearLayout to Frame layout.. and it works fine>> see update